# How to produce summary table?

Tags: r, stringr, tm

Suppose I have the following table named `df`.

```
A; B
A; B
B; C; D
C; D; E; F
```

Weight for each element of the row is computed as: `wt[i] <- 1/lengths(str_split(df[1],";"))`. **Ideally**, the above table weights attached to each elements seems the following.

```
0.5*A; 0.5*B
0.5*A; 0.5*B
0.333*B; 0.333*C; 0.333*D
0.25*C; 0.25*D; 0.25*E; 0.25*F
```

So, my intention is to have a table where the frequencies are the **sum of the weights**. The output I need is the following:

```
A     B     C     D      E     F
1  1.333 0.583  0.583  0.25  0.25
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option in `base R`.  After splitting the first column by `;` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), get the `lengths` of `list` and find the `sum` using `tapply`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(df[[1]], ";\\s*")
l1 <- lengths(lst1)
tapply(rep(1/l1, l1), unlist(lst1), sum)
#        A         B         C         D         E         F 
#1.0000000 1.3333333 0.5833333 0.5833333 0.2500000 0.2500000
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can use `separate_rows` to split up the column and then do a group by `summarise`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    separate_rows(v1) %>%
    add_count(rn) %>% 
    mutate(n = 1/n) %>% 
    group_by(v1) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(n))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  v1        n
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A     1    
#2 B     1.33 
#3 C     0.583
#4 D     0.583
#5 E     0.25 
#6 F     0.25
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("A; B", "A; B", "B; C; D", "C; D; E; F"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: The second data set is a kind of imaginary. What I really have is only the first data set. The program should calculate, assign the weights & produce the table by itself.

Comment: @Gadaa It is giving the expected output as in your post

Comment: I've one more question for you. `row.names = c(NA, -4L)` assumes the row names of length 4. But I want this length should be changed for each iteration (of course the data frame is also changed) since I'm going to use in the for loop. Is that possible to do so?

Comment: @Gadaa If you are talking about the data in my post.  it is from `dput` i.e. `dput(head(iris))` gives that format.  Can you please post as a new question with the required info so that it is more clear. thanks